# Помогите составить запрос sql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть таблица "costs" в котой есть поле "data" в етом поле вот что сохраняетса "30.09.2017 16:37:20" <- поле типа варчар.

суть в том чтоб виводить только те дание которие проведени в настоящий месяц а именно те (у которих 4 и 5 символ 09 ) вот..

как ето сделать?

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот как тут тогда пробовать вот етот запрос?
SELECT title FROM costs WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW())

сдесь создал новую таблицу и поде data уже timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> у которих 4 и 5 символ 09

```
-- var. 1
WHERE SUBSTRING(data FROM 4 FOR 2) = '09'
-- var. 2
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '.', 2), '.', -1) = '09'
-- var. 3
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s')) = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы то что Вам нужно, пробуйте... Только title на свой замените или * поставьте...

SELECT `title` FROM `costs` WHERE MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW())

Comment: поле (data) типа варчар! мне надо както определить вирезать с 4 по 6 символ но как

Comment: Этот запрос должен отработать и с варчар, если нет тогда лучше изменить тип на timestamp, в будущем будет легче либо перед формированием запроса получать дату, с помощью функции substr() указываем что ищем, получаем и формируем запрос...

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и 100% робочий способ

`SELECT * FROM costs WHERE MONTH(data) = 9`

Comment: У поля в вопросе тип `varchar`, так что сначала его надо к дате скастить как-то, наверное?

Comment: _**сдесь создал новую таблицу и поде data уже timestamp**_ автор переделал структуру таблицы, и тип не имеет значения в данном случае, главное чтобы значение поля было в формате Y.m.d или Y-m-d или Y-m-d h:i:s , тоесть год, потом месяц и за ним день